# Combing "click" and "hover" permanently?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, raphael

I want to have the click and drag functionality that Raphael.js provides, an example here: https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/.

The way you add and remove obstacles is great, it's essentially combining mousedown event and hover. But how on earth is that done? Any help please?

The closest I have is: https://codepen.io/ProgrammingKea/pen/ZowWJx

The salient bit is

```
  div.addEventListener("mousedown", function(ev){
     this.classList.add("obstacle");
     });
     div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev){
     this.classList.add("obstacle");
     });
     div.addEventListener("mouseup", function(ev){
     this.classList.add("obstacle");
     });
```

If you press large, then hover over the grid, that's the closest I've got.

But my issue is that its only hover here, I don't have the click functionality the above link does

Please post answers containing only vanilla JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe feels a bit clunky putting a handler on every element. I'd be tempted to put a handler on the main container and then check from there...

Maybe first add a bit of code to check if mouse is down.

```
var main = document.getElementById('main')

var mouseDown = 0;
main.onmousedown = function() { 
  mouseDown=1;
}
main.onmouseup = function() {
  mouseDown=0;
}
```

Then we can check if a mouse is down or over event...

```
main.addEventListener('mouseover', mousecheck)
main.addEventListener('mousedown', mousecheck)
```

Then we preventDefault (stop a drag).

If the mouse is down, and the element being acted on is a box, then we'll change it's colour.

```
function mousecheck( ev ) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if( mouseDown && ev.target.className.startsWith( 'box') ) {    
    ev.target.style.backgroundColor = ev.target.style.backgroundColor == "red" ? 'white' : 'red';
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeVyJP)

Comment: This is closer to what I was after thank you. This almost produces the functionality I want. My 2 questions are: 1. Why would a click break this functionality? (I can provide a code pen if you would like demoing how it breaks) 2.  How do I ensure there is a "create" drag and a "delete" drag like in the example. Do I need to check if we begin on an obstacle, then consider it a "create" drag?

Comment: I have solved it, thanks very much Ian. Adding an explicit "click" handler and a drag handler solved it. I may have some hair left at the end of this project now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
["mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseup"]
  .forEach(function (eve) {
    div.addEventListener(eve, function(ev){
      this.classList.add("obstacle");
    });
  });
```

Comment: This is helpful thanks, but it's still not the click and drag functionality that is evident on my above demonstration.

Comment: @kea Can you post the [mcve] you wish to solve? So that I can try making this code or something work on it `:)`

Comment: Okay. The goal for which I'm aiming for is this: https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/ 

To see what I mean, simply click and drag around the grid.

Now my code is: https://codepen.io/ProgrammingKea/pen/ZowWJx 

But as you notice the difference, mine doesn't require a click, as the above does.

So I need to combine a "click", then followed with a hover- kind of like a click and drag. But if you ONLY hover, do nothing.

The above are my event handlers I posted in the quesiton, which is the only bit that requires changing

Comment: @kea Okay, looking on it.

Comment: any luck? found anything?

Comment: @kea Nopes. Nothing yet. `:(`

Comment: I appreciate the help thank you! If you don't manage it no worries

Comment: @kea Glad you got your issue sorted. Enjoy!